# Inverse search using firefox

Tags: firefox, vim

I am writing a document using restructured text format in Turkish. I constantly review the output by using Firefox. As there is no spell checker in vim, I try to track down the spelling mistake by reading several times over Firefox and then try to correct the spelling mistake in source document (vim.) I wonder it is possible to make an inverse search so that whenever I come across a mistake in Firefox, clicking on it will bring me to corresponding word in vim.

thanks,

Comment: @romainl:  my question is more to find out that if any browser have inverse search functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* a spell checker in Vim.

Read `:help spell`, specifically the part on using custom spell files, `:help spell-mkspell`.